# .Net Core prevent memory allocation during += operator

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I've done some work in C++ optimizing libraries with intrinsics. Since .Net core now supports intrinsics with unsafe operations at least, I was going to see about writing a basic math/tensor lib for .net core. I'm writing benchmarks as I go along. I'm focusing on integrating some of the basic operations into a `Tensor` object now. In general, handling temporaries is going to be an important piece of the puzzle. I know in C++ there are some tricks with some intermediate objects that can prevent some reallocations. Curious if there is a way to trick C# into preventing the allocation when a += occurs. Otherwise, I'll just include the `SelfAdd` method and keep going.

```
using VM.Math;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;

namespace VM.Math;
{
    public class Tensor
    {
        private AlignedFloatArray data;
        public Shape Shape { get; private set; }

        Tensor SelfAdd(float x)
        {
            VM.Add(data,x,data);
            return this;
        }

        public static Tensor operator+(Tensor a, float b)
        {
            Tensor result = new Tensor(a.Shape);
            VM.Add(a.data,b,result.data);
            return result;
        }

        public static Tensor operator+(float a,Tensor b)
        {
            Tensor result = new Tensor(b.Shape);
            VM.Add(b.data,a,result.data);
            return result;           
        }

        public Tensor(Shape shape)
        {
            Shape = new Shape(shape);
            data = new AlignedFloatArray(Shape.Elements);
        }

        public Tensor(params int[] shape)
        {
            Shape = new Shape(shape);
            data = new AlignedFloatArray(Shape.Elements);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to overload compound assignment operators. Speculating a bit, this probably to maintain the invariant that `x op= y` is always the same as `x op y` followed by assignment to x. If it is individually overridden then that invariant can be broken. Note that assignment itself cannot be overridden either.

Comment: That's what i was afraid of ... I'll include the self add functions and just make a note of the unnecessary performance pitfall created by '+='.

Comment: If Tensor is itself somewhat small (e.g. only contains a reference to an array with the data), you might consider making it a struct. This would remove any allocations associated with the operators. If the struct itself is immutable, you could make it readonly and leverage readonly structs with the `in` parameter modifier to minimize copying anything when making method calls.